# Building VLC for iOS - GDrive path not found

Tags: ios, vlc

I am trying to compile the VLC V2.7.8 project for iOS by https://wiki.videolan.org/IOSCompile/.

Build it for devices "sh compileVLCforiOS.sh" occured error. The following picture:

[image: enter image description]

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source'
svn: E160013: '/svn/trunk/Source' path not found
```

This url already 404 error.

How do I fix this problem? Appreciate if any suggestion or idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-objectivec-client/hnZOY0LwtMc

you should replace the line

```
svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source GDrive
```

in compileVLCforiOS.sh with the line

```
git clone https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client GDrive
```